# How to get the legends from geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, web-gis

I am using geoserver 2.5.5. I have to get the legends of each category from different link. Now geoserver gives whole legend as a PNG image format using this link http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states

[image]

I need to have a link which gives each category of legend as a separate image like I need only <2M category in one link like this

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the `SCALE` option to select the scale(s) you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the optional RULE parameter in your request to specify the rule you want the legend for (see [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html))

You must have a Rule with a `Name` set, so if you modify the default population style:

```
 <Rule>
      <Name>top</Name>
      <Title>&gt; 4M</Title>

      <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
```

You can make a request like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states&RULE=top
```

Comment: Yes, but I am not clear about how to use RULE parameter exactly. At least I need one sample link which include RULE parameter.

Comment: So this Rule should be wriiten inside the sld file for styling or where? and how you relate the rule top with > 4M in legend.

Comment: Each rule can have a name (see my SLD example) and you can refer to it by that name in the GetLegend Request

Comment: Thank you for your help. can you please give me some link that has complete example of using rule. I am new to this and I can't understand it clearly.

Comment: Do you have some SLD? if so please paste it into the question